# Dealing with avro without namespace on spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, avro

I need to process some avro files with spark and I don't have any control on the generated avro files.

Each avro file got a schema (the same for each file) embeded on top of the file. I used that schema to generate related java classes. But this schema doesn't specify any namespace so classes are generated in the default namespace.

So, I can't reference those classes on my code (and i don't want to use reflection to keep things simple).

When i generate the same classes but in a namespace this time, spark complain about `org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to my.name.space.MyClass`

I think there will be a way but can't figure out.

Thanks in advance for your help !